# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message

Tags: mobile, appium-ios

When I tried to connect from appium to Real device facing following error. Anyone help to solve the issue

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message: 2020-06-27 23:03:32.086 xcodebuild[11529:3726320] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-akxhdiizyykdxefsthlnfyomlaiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb7c0b45580 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 0):

Solution that helped me, hope will solve your problem:

1. find out where web-driver-agent was installed on your machine (e.g. “/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent”);
2. there should be a file "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app";
3. copy it;
4. go to the folder that specified in your error message (NSFilePath);
5. if there is no directories as Build -> Products -> Debug-iphoneos
   then create all these directories manually;
6. paste file that was copied previously to the appropriate folder (your case "Debug-iphoneos").